# mpi alters a variable it shouldn't

Tags: fortran, mpi, fortran90

I have some Fortran code that I'm parallelizing with MPI which is doing truly bizarre things. First, there's a variable nstartg that I broadcast from the boss process to all the workers:

```
call mpi_bcast(nstartg,1,mpi_integer,0,mpi_comm_world,ierr)
```

The variable `nstartg` is never altered again in the program. Later on, I have the boss process send `eproc` elements of an array `edge` to the workers:

```
if (me==0) then
    do n=1,ntasks-1
        (determine the starting point estart and the number eproc
         of values to send)
        call mpi_send(edge(estart),eproc,mpi_integer,n,n,mpi_comm_world,ierr)
    enddo
endif
```

with a matching receive statement if `me` is non-zero. (I've left out some other code for readability; there's a good reason I'm not using scatterv.)

Here's where things get weird: the variable `nstartg` gets altered to `n` instead of keeping its actual value. For example, on process 1, after the mpi_recv, `nstartg = 1`, and on process 2 it's equal to 2, and so forth. Moreover, if I change the code above to

```
call mpi_send(edge(estart),eproc,mpi_integer,n,n+1234567,mpi_comm_world,ierr)
```

and change the tag accordingly in the matching call to mpi_recv, then on process 1, nstartg = 1234568; on process 2, nstartg = 1234569, etc.

What on earth is going on? All I've changed is the tag that mpi_send/recv are using to identify the message; provided the tags are unique so that the messages don't get mixed up, this shouldn't change anything, and yet it's altering a totally unrelated variable.

On the boss process, `nstartg` is unaltered, so I can fix this by broadcasting it again, but  that's hardly a real solution. Finally, I should mention that compiling and running this code using electric fence hasn't picked up any buffer overflows, nor did -fbounds-check throw anything at me.

Comment: Can you please post the most concise version of the code that reproduces this behavior?

Comment: Are you sure, your number of integers given by eproc is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most probable cause is that you pass an `INTEGER` scalar as the actual `status` argument to `MPI_RECV` when it should be really declared as an array with an implementation-specific size, available as the `MPI_STATUS_SIZE` constant:

```
INTEGER, DIMENSION(MPI_STATUS_SIZE) :: status
```

or

```
INTEGER status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)
```

The message tag is written to one of the status fields by the receive operation (its implementation-specific index is available as the `MPI_TAG` constant and the field value can be accessed as `status(MPI_TAG)`) and if your `status` is simply a scalar `INTEGER`, then several other local variables would get overwritten. In your case it simply happens so that `nstartg` falls just above `status` in the stack.

If you do not care about the receive status, you can pass the special constant `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE` instead.

Comment: Using `mpi_status_ignore` fixed it, thanks very much!